# Number of points of non-differentiabilty of $f(x)=(arc\cos x)|\sin (kx)|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Consider a function $$f(x)=(arc \cos x)|\sin(kx)|$$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\leq 100$.

If for four consecutive values of $k=\{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4\}$ ,

$f(x)$ has equal number of points of non-differentiabilty,

then which of the following statement(s) is/are true

(1) One of the possible values of  $k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4$ is $94$.

(2) One of the possible values of  $k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4$ is $182$.

(3) One of the possible values of  $k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4$ is $358$.

(4) $\sum_{k=1}^{100}$(number of points of non-differentiability of $f(x)$) is $3216$.

**My Attempt**

Clearly $f(x)$ is defined for $x\in [-1,1]$ and is non differentiable when $\sin (kx)=0$ i.e $x=\frac{k\pi}{n}$ .

Since $-1\leq \frac{k\pi}{n}\leq 1$ we have $-\frac{n}{\pi}\leq k\leq\frac{n}{\pi}$

From here onwards I am not able to think further

Comment: By cos^(-1), what do you mean? Do you mean the inverse function of cosine, also know as arccosine? Or do you mean the reciprocal of cosine (also known as secant)?

Comment: It is arccosine

Comment: Your function is defined for all real x (at least). Are you not restricting the domain to some subset of this?

Comment: arc(cos x) is defined for $-1\leq x\leq 1$

Comment: Sorry, I erroneously thought you were *composing* the arccos function with the |sin|| function. Instead I see that they are being multiplied.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ycd3bw1v4q